# Holomorphic function vanishes on the boundary

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle

Let $f \in \mathcal{O}(D) \cap \mathcal{C}(\overline{D})$, $D$ - a bounded region in $\mathbb{C}$. Suppose that $f(z)=0$ for $z \in \partial D$.

Prove that $f(z)=0$ for all $z \in D$.

At first I thought about identity principle, but there we require that $f=g$ on a set $A$ with accumulation point in $int D$ .

And Poisson formula works for a circle - here we have an arbitrary closed region.

Could you tell me what I could use to prove the statement above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real and imaginary parts are continuous so they reach a maximum. If the maximum is nonzero it must be reached in the interior.

Comment: Therefore $f= const = c$ in $D$, but $f = 0$ on $\partial D$ nad due to continuity of $f$ on the closure of $D$, we must have $c=0$. Is that correct?

Comment: That's where I wanted to go, thanks for completing the argument.